# stop auto convert timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js

Java script automatic converts timezone, how do i stop it?

i have created an api which fetch data from mysql table and display it into json format, but the problem is except datetime column every thing remain as expected.
only timestamp fields(DateTime Columns) automatic changed why?

**Mysql Stored Procedure Output**

[image]

**JsonResponse**

```
[
    {
        "OrderId": 2164294,
        "MRP": 270,
        "LedId_Party": "757",
        "ItemDetailId": "10000196",
        "NAME": "Retail Graph Admin",
        "OrderNo": "RTG7",
        "OrderDate": "2018-10-25T11:31:29.896Z",
        "Qty": 15,
        "Remarks": "test order",
        "CompanyId": " R01142\\d",
        "OtherPartyCode": "757",
        "PartyName": "Tanaya das",
        "OtherProductCode": "10000196",
        "ProductName": "ROLIFLO OD CAP 404 10S",
        "Company": "RANBAXY  RESPIRATORY",
        "Packing": "10S",
        "Free": 1,
        "CreatedDate": "2018-10-25T11:31:29.896Z",
        "Scheme": null,
        "PTR": 0,
        "Delivery": 1,
        "SalesmanCode": null,
        "DeliveryMode": "To Deliver",
        "ProductRemarks": null,
        "SchemeType": null
    },
    {
        "OrderId": 2164294,
        "MRP": 198.25,
        "LedId_Party": "757",
        "ItemDetailId": "10000426",
        "NAME": "Retail Graph Admin",
        "OrderNo": "RTG7",
        "OrderDate": "2018-10-25T11:31:29.896Z",
        "Qty": 20,
        "Remarks": "PR:test product GR:test order",
        "CompanyId": " R01142\\d",
        "OtherPartyCode": "757",
        "PartyName": "Tanaya das",
        "OtherProductCode": "10000426",
        "ProductName": "BAKFLEX 8MG 10S",
        "Company": "INTAS[ARRON]9332940350[SUMAN]",
        "Packing": "10S",
        "Free": 0,
        "CreatedDate": "2018-10-25T11:31:29.896Z",
        "Scheme": null,
        "PTR": 0,
        "Delivery": 1,
        "SalesmanCode": null,
        "DeliveryMode": "To Deliver",
        "ProductRemarks": "test product",
        "SchemeType": null
    }
]
```

**Nodecode:**

```
app.get('/Admin/api/GetPurchaseOrderToUpload', async (req, res) => {
        const jsonobject = await objPurchaseOrder.GetPurchaseOrderToUpload(DecryptedDistributorCode);
        return res.status(200).json(jsonobject);
    });
```

**PurchaseOrder.js**

```
var pool =  require('../models/poolconnection');
// const mongoose = require('mongoose');
function GetPurchaseOrderToUpload(DistributorCode) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        var query = 'call PR_GetPurchaseOrderToUpload(?)';
        pool.query(query,[DistributorCode],(err,result,fields) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else {
                resolve(result[0]);
            }
        });
    });
}
module.exports = {
    GetPurchaseOrderToUpload: GetPurchaseOrderToUpload,
 }
```

Comment: The timestamp that you receive is the ISO format. It show the dates/hours in UTC

Comment: so how do i stop to convert it?

Comment: Are you sure that you database stores data in a TimeZone and not in UTC ?

Comment: since you haven't included any code showing how you actually move the data from one format to another, it's impossible for us to know what processes might be operating on it to change the way the date is output.

Comment: @ADyson, updated question with code

Comment: Thanks, but we're still missing the SQL procedure, which is also part of the process. And we also don't know for sure what pools.query does. At what point does the server convert the data into JSON, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to set dateStrings property to true for mysql connection

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret',
  dateStrings : true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Json response is generated from Web API(Node application). Probably you should stick with one timezone or UTC timezone in server level itself. You can use moment.tz to convert the datetime to specific timezone, it really helps a lot.

> https://momentjs.com/timezone/